# What is the best way to Partition a RealmList

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

My use case is to display the result of a realm query (realm list) in chunks of 4, it will be displayed inside a recycler view which is placed inside a viewpager, For this purpose, I'm trying to partition the result as below. Is the correct way to do it or is there any other recommendations.

```
        int orderNumberToBeDisplayed = 4;//<--- This is a configuration 

        RealmList<RealmList<OrderData>> finalList = new RealmList<>();
        RealmList<OrderData> partitionList = new RealmList<>();
        for (int counter = 0 ; counter < orderList.size(); counter++ ){
            partitionList.add(orderList.get(counter));
            if(counter%orderNumberToBeDisplayed == 0){
                finalList.add(partitionList);
                partitionList.clear();
            }
        }
```

The topmost list will be for the view pager the inner list will be for the recycler view which is placed inside the viewpager.

Before introducing the realm we were able to do the above partitioning using [Lists.partition](https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-split#guava_list) from google guava library for the direct api list object that was returned from our API.

As Realm is lazy loading does doing the above load the result to the memory even though only the 1st 4 items will be viewed on the initial recycler view of the viewpager whereas the reset will be shown when the page is swiped

Comment: Those are not real RealmLists and you should be using regular `ArrayList` instead for this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EpicPandaForce. I'm not doing this I'm using the whole result and then using the get(i) to get the results in batch. As realm list are lazy-loaded

Comment: RealmLists that are created with `new RealmList()` are not lazy-loaded, managed RealmLists are

Comment: Yeah orderList here is a managed list. doing the above would make it unmanaged as well if I'm correct